# Не работают детальные страницы новости при изменении разводящей страницы

Tags: битрикс

Появилась необходиомость изменить разводящую страницу с комплексным компонентом новостей на кастомную, статическую.
На индексной странице кроме кода вставки хедера и футера, ну и самого кода комплексного компонента - ничего нет. Я удалил код комплесконо компонента. Прописал код статичный, на странцие присутствуют ссылки на детальные страницы новостей из этого компонента.
Но теперь они не открываются, а открывается та же кастомная разводящая странциа по всем этим ссылкам (сами ссылки в адреснйо строке меняются).

Я понимаю, что за их вывод отвечает комплексный компонент новостей. Который я удалил.
И вот задача: как мне отобразить на странице свою кастомную статическую страницу, вместо инфоблока, но что бы детальные новости все таки открывались?

**UPD:** цель состоит в том, что бы на разводящей странице был список новостей, часть новостей - это ссылки на детальные страницы внутри сайта, а часть - это произвольный текст со ссылками на внешние сайты. По итогу получается, что совмещен статический и динамическйи контент на странцие должен быть.

Даже если я буду править стили комплексного компонента новостей, то мне будет все равно необходимо добавить на страницу свой код, а он в совю очередь, отображается на страницах детального просмотра новости.

Внутри сайта структура имеет внутренние разделы, в которых есть элементы (детальная новость). Но от разделов можно отказаться, все новости вывести в одну кучу.

Попробовал убрать комплексный компонент, вставить список новостей вместо него, и сделать детальную страницу новости (ничего не получилось, наверное настроил не так) Но еще важно что бы сохранялась структура ссылки - site.ru/news/news_name
Если я добавлю страницу detail.php - ссылка же на детальную новость будет содержать в адресе detail.php=news_name

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: Отказаться от комплексного компонента новостей, создать отдельный файл для новостей (например, detail.php), поместить в него компонент news.detail, настроить инфоблок на него и по необходимости отредактировать urlrewrite.php.

Например, ссылки на новости у вас имеют вид "/news/news_name". Значит, в файле urlrewrite.php есть правило типа:

```
    7 => array(
        'CONDITION' => '#^/news/(.+)#',
        'RULE' => 'CODE=$1',
        'ID' => NULL,
        'PATH' => '/index.php',
        'SORT' => 100,
    )
```

Замените index.php на detail.php . Теперь обработкой ссылок будет заниматься файл detail.php . Вставьте в этот файл компонент bitrix:news.detail, укажите параметр `"ELEMENT_CODE" => $_REQUEST["CODE"]`

Вариант 2: Скопировать шаблон комплексного компонента news в шаблон сайта.
При этом скопируется комплексный шаблон, внутри которого есть куча шаблонов для простых компонентов. Отредактируйте шаблон простого компонента news.list. Важно отредактировать именно внутренний шаблон, а не создавать отдельный шаблон для news.list, иначе он не подцепится комплексным компонентом. Все изменения будут отражены только на списке новостей, а не на странице новости.

Comment: А можно поподробнее описать действия по первому варианту?

Comment: Написал подробнее.

Comment: Блин что то не выходит...при переходе пишет Элемент не найден...
Что Вы имели ввиду под "Настроить под него инфоблок?
И мне кажется я не верно настроил компонент...
ID Новости ={$_REQUEST["ID"]}

И шаблоны ссылок по умолчанию из инфоблока берется же, с комплексным компонентом работало же ведь.

Comment: Вообще странно, когда вношу изменения в настройки компонента - из urlrewritre пропадает правило которое я добавляю

Comment: Ставьте своим правилам 'ID'=>NULL, иначе их может переписать соответствующий компонент.

Comment: Исправил ответ, учитывая, что у вас привязка не к номеру новости, а к её коду. Ну и дополнил второй вариант.